# Complex to real eigenvalues of a matrix when multiplied with itself

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the fact that a matrix has complex eigenvalues for $n$ power of matrix such that $0\le n\le21$ and has real roots for $n = 22$. The matrix is a square matrix that is $2 \times 2$.

I am trying to understand this intuitively and mathematically - what does this mean when a matrix has complex roots for some power of $n$ and then has real roots for some power of $n$?

I know that when the matrix is raised to $n$ times, its eigenvalues are also raised to $n$ times. So, the given matrix has $2$ eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. And I am unable to take the thought process further. Please kindly help me understand the concept.

Comment: Your problem is badly written. I assume they want you to find a matrix $A \in \mathcal{M}_2 (\mathbb{R})$ such that for $0< k < 22, \, A^k$ has only non-real eigenvalues and $A^{22}$ has only real eigenvalues. In other words, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda$ is a primitive $11th$ root of the unity. Hint: try a rotation matrix!

Comment: For example, the eigenvalues could be $\;\pm \sqrt[11]i\;$, so that the $\;22-th\;$ power would be $\;i^2=-1\in\Bbb R\;$, say... And I understand that when you write "complex" you in fact mean complex non-real.

Comment: What sort of matrix has no lines of invariant points the first 21 times you repeat it, but does on the 22nd?